# Грамотное обновление данные в БД

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

Возникла потребность в обновлении большого прайса (~70к записей) на сайте. Данные получаю по API.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, грамотный и оптимальный способ обновления.
Какие вижу варианты я:

1. Пройтись в цикле по каждому товару -> обратиться к БД и обновить цену (даже если не изменилась).
2. Получить все данные из таблицы, сравнить циклом в цикле, удалить предыдущие данные и записать новые (что-то бредово звучит этот вариант).

Comment: в первом случае подразумевается 1 sql запрос, или туда сюда 70тыс раз update ?

Comment: *Данные получаю по API.* Сразу всё обновление или по одной записи?

Comment: *Какие вижу варианты я* 70к записей - это мелочь, а не "большой". Лучший вариант - получить всё, возможно слить во временную таблицу, а потом, в зависимости от идеологии обновления, либо INSERT .. ODKU, либо REPLACE INTO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Получить все данные из БД. Поместить их в массив с ключом по ID записи или другому признаку, по которому идет сопоставление с данными, получаемыми по API. (далее $db_data)
2. В цикле пройтись по данным API, получая по ключу из массива $db_data состояние в БД. Если строки с данным ключом не найдено - добавляем новую запись в БД. Если запись есть, сравниванием поля с данными, если данные отличаются, выдаем update. Вне зависимости от того менялись данные или нет, удаляем из массива $db_data запись с текущим ключом.
3. По завершении цикла по данным API, все что осталось в $db_data, это то, чего не нашлось в данных API. Удаляем эти записи из БД

P.S. При получении данных API не забыть сделать проверки, что данные действительно получены. Что бы пустой массив с данными не привел к удалению всех данных из БД на шаге 3.